# Set geodatabase as outfolder in ArcGIS 10.7 when creating tool in Python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to specify a file location for an output file when creating a python toolbox tool, but the tool continues to output the file to the default geodatabase. I have tried to set the env.workspace within the tool, but clearly this is not the right approach. Here is a code snippet for the parameters I have created to specify the outfolder and the outfile name:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    # First parameter. Input file
    inFile = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input File",
        name="inFile",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    inFile.filter.list = ["Point"] ## restrict to point files
    
    # Second parameter. outfolder
    outFolder = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output Folder",
        name="outFolder",
        datatype="DEWorkspace",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
        
    # Input File Parameter
    outFile = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output File",
        name="outFile",
        datatype="DEFile",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Output")
```

Unfortunately, the tool continues to write to the default database.

How do I change this behavior?

Comment: Why are you doing this in validation script, when this can be easily done in source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DEFile is a file on a disk, not a feature class or table inside a geodatabase.

You can either set the outFile to a string and then join outFolder and outFile.

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    inFile = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input File",
        name="inFile",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    inFile.filter.list = ["Point"]

    outFolder = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output Folder",
        name="outFolder",
        datatype="DEWorkspace",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    outFolder.type = ["Local Database"]
        
    outFile = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output File",
        name="outFile",
        datatype="GPString",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """Creates a line from the in_feature to the closest near feature,
    within the search tolerance."""
    in_features = parameters[0].valueAsText
    out_folder = parameters[1].valueAsText
    out_file = parameters[2].valueAsText

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    desc = arcpy.Describe(in_features)
    # Create output feature class
    arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
        out_folder, out_file, geometry_type="POINT",
        spatial_reference=desc.spatialReference)
```

If your geodatabase already exists, then you could just prompt for the output (DEFeatureClass or DETable). Then use the path from that object.

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    inFile = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input File",
        name="inFile",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    inFile.filter.list = ["Point"]

    out_feature_class = arcpy.Parameter(
        name='out_feature_class',
        displayName='Output Feature Class',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Output',
        datatype='DEFeatureClass',
        multiValue=False)

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """Creates a line from the in_feature to the closest near feature,
    within the search tolerance."""
    in_features = parameters[0].valueAsText
    out_feature_class = parameters[1].valueAsText

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    desc = arcpy.Describe(in_features)
    path, name = os.path.split(out_feature_class)
    # Create output feature class
    arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
        path, name, geometry_type="POINT",
        spatial_reference=desc.spatialReference)
```